# Help following instructions (stuck at editing a file)

Tags: command-line, scripts, android, c, sdl

I'm following [these instructions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Android). This is what I've done so far:

- Installed JDK
- Downloaded NDK & SDK, extracted them and MOVED them to `usr/src`
- Configured my `$PATH`
- Ran `android` and now I'm installing API **15**

Now I am on this step:

> Edit build-scripts/androidbuild.sh, find the $ANDROID update project
>   line, and add --target 'android-XX' to it (replace XX with your
>   installed API number above)

Where is `build-scripts/androidbuild.sh`?
Ran `find /usr/src/ -name build-scripts/androidbuild.sh`, no results. What should I do.

I just want to run my C + SDL program on android. I don't know anything about linux stuff. Any way I could accomplish this via lubuntu software center?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838635/compiling-sdl2-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `./build-scripts/androidbuild.sh` is in the source code folder of `libSDL`.

Look [here](https://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) and download the source code archive

E.G.:

```
wget https://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.3.tar.gz
tar xf SDL2-2.0.3.tar.gz
cd SDL2-2.0.3
```

After that you can see the folder `build-scripts`

```
./build-scripts/androidbuild.sh
```